# VCL for Web skins/themes?

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl, skins, intraweb

Has anyone created a skin/theme wrapper for Intraweb/VCL for Web ?

The default look of the grids etc are very dated..

Any info appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

CSS is the best way to make your web pages look fancy.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [Intraweb components TMS offers](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/products.asp?t=iw).  Grid example is [here](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsiwpro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is an old question anyway i give my answer. I use [these CGDEVTOOLS Intraweb components](https://www.cgdevtools.com/products/iwcgjquery-suite/), they make an app look modern and they have an handful of features that extend Intraweb, expecially on the ajax side. They are very good, but use them only if you are serious about  Intraweb. It could be strange to start sudying Intraweb in 2018.